# Can I use the Creation Spell to create potions and poisons?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

The [Creation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/creation) spell description states it creates a nonliving object. Can I create things like *healing potions* and poisons as long as I have a potion or poison to base them on?

Answer (score 7):

You *can't* create potions in this way, because they are magical in nature. They definitely don't come under 'nonliving object of vegetable matter' or under 'mineral objects'.

To create poisons, on the other hand, *might* be possible. The examples given for 'nonliving object of vegetable matter' are "soft goods" (whatever that means), rope, wood, or something similar. So this doesn't seem to be an intended use for this spell, but if you can find a poison that is made solely out of vegetable material then I can't find a reason to disallow it. Of course, none of the poisons currently available explicitly come from plants, so this might be difficult.

Note that this creates an extremely strange interaction: What happens if you poison someone with a poison that ceases to exist while the person is still poisoned? It's a complicated enough question to:

a) Be worth a separate question of its own

and

b) Suggest that this really isn't something that's meant to be able to happen.

Comment: Real-world poisons made from plant material: Cyanide (bitter almonds, apple seeds), various Alkaloids (potatoes, tomatoes, nightshade, belladonna, pepper, tobacco), ricin (castor oil plant).  Real world poisons from mineral sources: heavy metals (could you give somebody radiation poisoning?), sulfur dioxide (gas), ground silica fragments (ie, ground glass), chlorine (gas), radon (gas, radioactive).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse real world has nothing to do with 5e poisons. There was a DMG preview that explicitly showed all poisons creatable and they are not from real world chemical sources, but mainly from magical animal like wyverns and giant snakes.

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith - The section where the effects are listed is labelled "Sample Poisons", and in the crafting section a line explicitly states "At your discretion, the character can craft other kinds of poison."  The list isn't exhaustive (and doing such would seem to be counter to the general design direction of this edition).  The name "Essence of Ether" suggests that real-world chemicals _are_ viable - although no longer (commonly) used, there was an anesthetic gas often [known as ether](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diethyl_ether).